# Az Powershell New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment which id is which?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I have this so far

```
 New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $global:app_object_id -Id $global:user_id  -ResourceId $role.Id
```

Not sure if the above is correct.
But it also wants a `-PrincipalId` to continue.
Can anyone please confirm if I am getting my existing `Ids` correct and what to put for the `-PrincipalId`

Comment: Please post your update as an answer.

Comment: done, I thought I wasn't able to do that till later.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind I found it

```
 $response = New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment 
        -ObjectId $global:app_object_id 
        -Id $role.Id 
        -PrincipalId $global:user_id  
        -ResourceId $global:app_object_id
```

Or at least, this seems to work for me.